# Audio output distorted with any FFT Windowing other than rectangular

Tags: fft, audio, window-functions, ifft

For an experiment i have a simple application that takes a quadrature signal from a radio and then does the following:
Complex FFT -> Inverse FFT -> Cartesian to Polar -> audio out
If I tune the radio to an AM signal I can demodulate it perfectly well by this but it depends on how the FFT is processed.
In the FFT routine, I apply a window and if it is anything other than a rectangular window the sound is distorted even to the point where it's only noise.  The sample thing if there is any FFT sample overlap.  Why is this the case?
As I mentioned this is an experiment.  I already have a fully functional spectrum scope which provides very good resolution using a Blackman window and sample overlap.  I wish to add demodulation of the signals in the frequency domain starting from the spectrum but this is problematic.
Thanks for any insight (I'm a beginner in DSP).

Comment: May I ask what's the purpose of doing an FFT followed by its inverse?

Comment: Hi, the initial FFT is done to obtain a spectrum.  In this spectrum there are a number of signals.  The idea is to eventually select these signals, and then demodulate them.